# How do I convert a Twitter API Pull into an Array in Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I am trying to create a stream that includes Twitter data + my app's but I'm having trouble with this because Twitter's data isn't properly coming out as an array. This is my code:

```
answers = Answer.find(:all, :conditions => {:user_id => @user_id }, :limit => 20)
tweets = Twitter::Search.new(params[:username])

@feed = (answers + tweets).order_by(&:created_at)
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the [Twitter Gem](http://twitter.rubyforge.org/)?  In which case, the Search class is Enumerable and you can therefore call to_a on an instance of it. So...

```
tweets = Twitter::Search.new(params[:username]).to_a
@feed = (answers + tweets).order_by(&:created_at)
```

Comment: Thanks, and Cool that managed to pull off part of it. It converted to an array but I get an error with the next line of code. It's not letting me sort the two together. (changed order_by to sort_by)

Error message: 

ArgumentError in HomeController#show

comparison of ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone with String failed

Any ideas?